# Python how to align text using for loops?

Tags: python

this is an add on from a previous question. The function takes in 6 arguments that determines both the information displayed and how its being displayed. First_name and last_name as a string. Align1, column 1 alignment, a string, either R, L, or C. length1: column 1 length, an integer. align2: column 2 alignment, a string, either R, L, or C and length2: column 2 length, an integer. The output i get from the function ive made thus far is shown below

```
def display_name(first_name,last_name,align1,length1,align2,length2):
  str = ""

 #first name
 #align left
  if align1 == "L":
    str = first_name
    for i in range(0, length1 - len(first_name)):
        str += " "
    print("|First name|")       
    print("|" + str + "|")

  #align right
  if align1 == "R":
      
    for i in range(0, length1 - len(first_name)):
      str += " "
    str += first_name               
    print("|First name|")       
    print("|" + str + "|")


  #align centre
  if align1 == "C":
    
    for i in range(0, (length1 - len(first_name))//2):
      str += " "
    str += first_name 
    for i in range(0, length1 - len(str)):
      str += " "
    print("|First name|")       
    print("|" + str + "|")

 #last name
 #align left
  if align2 == "L":
    str = last_name
    for i in range(0, length2 - len(last_name)):
        str += " "
    print("|last name|")       
    print("|" + str + "|")


  #align right
  if align2 == "R":
      
    for i in range(0, length2 - len(last_name)):
      str += " "
    str += last_name               
    print("|last name|")       
    print("|" + str + "|")

  #align centre
  if align2 == "C":
    
    for i in range(0, (length2 - len(last_name))//2):
      str += " "
    str += last_name 
    for i in range(0, length2 - len(str)):
      str += " "
    print("|last name|")       
    print("|" + str + "|")

display_name("John", "Smith", "L", 12, "R", 10)
```

```
|First name|
|John        |
|last name|
|John             Smith|
```

Ive managed to display the following, showing the alignment does work but I require a different output shown below

```
|First name  | Last name|
|John        |     Smith|
```

Im having difficulty trying to reach this expected outcome and require assitance. Thankyou

Comment: Why not just put it in a dict and use `tabulate`?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is string padding using `str.ljust` , `str.rjust`, and `str.center` respectively for align left, align right, and centering.

```
def display_name(first_name,last_name,align1,length1,align2,length2):
    if align1 == 'R':
        align1 = str.rjust
    elif align1 == 'L':
        align1 = str.ljust
    elif align1 == 'C':
        align1 = str.center
    else:
        # stops function because of invalid argument
        print('Invalid argument for parameter align1')
        return None
    
    if align2 == 'R':
        align2 = str.rjust
    elif align2 == 'L':
        align2 = str.ljust
    elif align2 == 'C':
        align2 = str.center
    else:
        # stops function because of invalid argument
        print('Invalid argument for parameter align2')
        return None
    
    def pad_first_name(name):
        '''Pads first_name with whitespace'''
        return align1(name, max(length1, len('First Name')))
    def pad_last_name(name):
        return align1(name, max(length2, len('Last Name')))
    
    print('|'+pad_first_name('First Name')+'|'+pad_last_name('Last Name')+'|')
    print('|'+pad_first_name(first_name)+'|'+pad_last_name(last_name)+'|')    

display_name('Guido', 'van Russo', 'C', 7, 'R', 20)
print()
display_name('Leonardo', 'Di Caprio', 'L', 3, 'L', 16)
```

```
|First Name|     Last Name      |
|  Guido   |     van Russo      |

|First Name|Last Name       |
|Leonardo  |Di Caprio       |
```